# how to set my website in order to visit my site without adding "/wordpress"?

Tags: wordpress, web

When I visit my website, I have to type "mysite.com/wordpress".
How do I set my website in order to visit my site via "mysite.com"?
I have tried some methods, but they didn't work. Editing .htaccess or wp-config.php?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If its not in the .htaccess or your apache config then it's likely just the directory structure. In that case, you need to SSH or FTP into your website's root directory. On a LAMP build it's usually something like var/www/html or home/{username}/html. If you are on shared hosting, your users usually only has permission to the directory above the one that your domain points to.

Once you've located the wordpress directory, go back one directory (to the parent of wordpress). Move the files from the wordpress directory to the parent directory. You probably need to modify the wp config to reflect that change.

This article (on the WP site) disucsses in detail how change the location of your files:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress